# Mi datatable de jquery me repite los registros de forma muy repetida

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Actualmente quiero llenar mi datatable con  jquery y lo hago de forma medianamente exitosa salvo que me repite los valores de forma indefinida, actualmente de mi BD solamente obtengo un registro pero se llena el datatable con muchos muchos registros.

Codigo php:

```
        include "../Config/db_connect.php";

        $sql = "select tabla_usuario.NombreUsuario,tabla_usuario.DescripcionUser,tb_proyecto.NombreP,(select tb_perfil.NombrePerfil from tb_perfil where tb_perfil.IdPerfil=tabla_usuario.idPerfil ) as perfil from tb_peticiones inner join tb_usuario as tabla_usuario on tabla_usuario.idUsuario=tb_peticiones.idUsuario inner join tb_proyecto on tb_proyecto.idProyecto=tb_peticiones.idProyecto";

  $rawdata = array(); //creamos un array
  $i=0;

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        $tbodyPeticiones="";
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$rawdata[$i] = $row;
                $i++;
            }
        }


        mysqli_close($conn);


echo json_encode(array("data" => $rawdata));
```

Codigo Ajax:

```
   $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                  "method":"GET",
            "url" : "Core/Peticiones/Peticiones.php?Accion=loadPeticiones"
        },
        "columns":[
        {"data":"NombreUsuario"},
         {"data":"DescripcionUser"},
          {"data":"perfil"},
           {"data":"NombreP"}
        ]

    } );
```

Codigo HTML:

```
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                  <thead>
                                                            <th>NombreUsuario</th>
                                        <th>DescripcionUser</th>
                                        <th>perfil</th>
                                        <th>NombreP</th>
                  </thead>
<tbody  >
  
</tbody>
                </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la imagen de arriba es el resultado final

**Actualización:**

El archivo de .php me retorna el siguiente JSON ya que lo imprimi en un alert();

```
{"data":[{"NombreUsuario":"Nuevo","DescripcionUser":"Soy un buen programado web","NombreP":"Proyecto de Salma","perfil":"Arquitecto"}]}
```

Comment: Según lo que veo `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` nunca termina el while es por eso que te crea indefinidos registros.

Comment: ¿Verificaste los datos obtenidos en la consulta SQL? Puede que ya vengan repetidos ahí. Si es así deberás verificar que los `JOIN` están bien y que no hay datos locos en alguna tabla que causan duplicidad.

Comment: @Carlos1232 ya actulice el post y lo que me retorna el archivo .php es solo un registro ademas si te das cuenta me hace un solo registro en muchas paginas del datatable y se supone que tengo un select que me permite 10 registrors por pagina, no se si eso tambien tenga algo que ver.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya actualice mi post con el json que me retorna el archivo .php y solo viene un registro.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar esto: `"serverSide": true,` por esto: `"serverSide": false,`